# DWARF DI with generated C code?

Tags: c, dwarf

I can't seem to find any good documentation for the DWARF DI format to answer my question. I'm writing a language that compiles to C, is there any way that I can produce DWARF Debug Information into the C code or is it assembly only?

Is it *impossible* to add debug information to some (generated) C code other than using primitive stuff that isn't as good like `#line` and the `#file` directives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you'll compile the generated C with debug info (-g), so what you're asking is how to have additional DWARF records that describe your high level language. Conceivable approaches:

(1) edit the object file to augment the DWARF records for the C code. I don't know of an existing tool, perhaps doable with [libdwarf](https://www.prevanders.net/dwarf.html) or [pyelftools](https://github.com/eliben/pyelftools).

(2) find a way to "smuggle" extra DWARF records through the compiler, e.g. somewhat as linker commands can be given through #pragmas. However I don't know of a compiler that supports this.

(3) LLVM has support for debug records in the [IR representation](http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html) . You could use clang to compile your generated C to IR (`clang foo.c -S -emit-llvm -target arm -o foo.ll`), then augment foo.ll, then generate the .o (`llc foo.ll`), ready for linking.

The third option seems likely to be the easiest.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I might give the third option a go!

Answer (score 2):

It can be done for some things, if you assume your compiler can emit assembly.  For an example of this, see [my favorite gdb test case](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/testsuite/gdb.dwarf2/pr10770.c;h=64dfc91ce751c45d5c674d25c137c50a42e95e3c;hb=HEAD).

Normally this isn't done, though.  It can be quite hard to get right.  Nowadays it's better to either write your compiler to be a direct front-end to GCC or LLVM; or to write gdb or lldb helper scripts to make debugging the generated C code simpler.

Comment: "It can be quite hard to get right" - and that's even with the difficulty normalised against working with DWARF data at all.